# Unable to install pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have a fresh installation of vscode, python and anaconda on my laptop. In the extensions for vscode, i have installed the python extension. Pylance is supposed to be installed along with python, but it is stuck at installing and never finishes.[image]
Anyway i can install pylance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem today as well. The error in my VSCode/VSCodium output > python window was:

> Command failed: /bin/python2 -I ... Unknown option: -I

I tried the command with python3 and didn't seem to do anything even though there was no error.

These steps fixed it for me.

1. Download the latest vsix file: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance
2. Go into VSCode/VSCodium Extensions and at top click '...' then Install from VSIX.

https://community.particle.io/t/how-to-install-a-vscode-extension-from-a-vsix-file/51014